# Laravel new project with vagrant/homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I just followed the [manual at the laravel website](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#first-steps) and installed homestead.
When running `vagrant up` it runs fine and I can connect using `vagrant ssh`.
There is only one step I can not find, how do i start a new laravel project using the vagrant installation.
I can ssh to the vargant machine so I assume I should run `laravel new someproject` somewhere on the vagrant environment?

In my Homestead.yaml I have:

```
folders:
    -   map: D:/Documents/repos/someproject
        to: /home/vagrant/someproject

sites:
    -   map: someproject.test
        to: /home/vagrant/someproject/public
```

Where someproject is currently empty as i want to start a new project and not work on an existing one. I do not have composer/php/mysql on my windows machine but I assume the benefit of the vargant box is that it has all the needed dependencies and I should run it in vagrant.
I tried running it in /home/vagrant but i got:

> laravel new someproject
>
> In NewCommand.php line 110:
>
> Application already exists!
>
> new [--dev] [--auth] [-f|--force] [--] []

'
So how do I start the new laravel project after installing vagrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says that the application someproject already exists. Does the folder already exists in `/home/vagrant`?

Make sure to add the domain to your hosts file. For Ubuntu, this would be in`/etc/` folder. If you want to access your website through `someproject.test` add

```
192.188.10.10 someproject.test
```

to your `hosts` file.

The site link has to be mention in you `Homestead.yaml`

```
sites:
    -   map: someproject.test
        to: /home/vagrant/somneproject/public
```

Make sure to call

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

after saving the changes.

Now if you type `someproject.test` into the browser you should see the default page (assuming you have generate the key for your laravel application, otherwise you may get an error).

Comment: Hi @adam the manual says specifically to map it to single projects. "You should always map individual projects to their own folder mapping instead of mapping your entire ~/code folder.". yes the folder exists, i also made a public folder in my D:/Documents/repos/someproject so that it would not have an non existing file dependency
  directory to be sure it would not fail on that

Comment: I tried your solution,, updated the file, run vagrant reload --provision, run vagrant up, but when i run vagrant ssh it is asking for a password, I tried `secret` but it keeps asking for the password

Comment: I removed everything and tried it with your code, It dosnt recognise the laravel command anymore but 'composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog' seems to work

Comment: I created the new project but how can I visit the newly created project, i have the feeling i miss a big chunk of documentation that tells how to use homestead for actual development. I tried visiting 192.168.10.10 and someproject.test.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart sorry your right, the way you did it is also correct, in https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead they said, you may map it to the code directory that contains all projects.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart to your question with ssh and the pass - try as default password "vagrant" or read https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/1253 for more.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart to your question how to reach the website, you need to modify your `hosts` file, I updated my post. But it sounds like you skipped the https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#hostname-resolution section from the docs which explain that.